Console syslogd code 360
On MacOS's Console app which lists syslogd events on the system.log, there are no public definitions for the error numbers which is unhelpful and not in-line with transparency of linux systems.  Apple support said I would need to come into the store for their engineers to try and answer my question (as stated below).  Event id descriptions should be public so we can diagnose our computer issues.
As a computer programmer with many years experience on linux (as we know Darwin is based on Free BSD), I've never had such a problem finding codes such as this to debug (in this case disconnection issues).  In particular, on my m1 laptop, I get the below message, the question is what does code 360 mean?
Sep 10 11:01:49 Mycomp syslogd[360]: ASL Sender Statistics

As an example, in the following answer on the Apple forum, the meaning of the code (in that case 337) was never stated.  Knowing your error codes is step 1.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254267411
I hope this question is not removed because having access to event codes is essential to identify proper operation of our Mac computers.  See the following for general info about syslog events. I might find this number by searching through low level linux logs using the terminal, but I shouldn't have to:
https://ackcent.com/basics-linux-events-logging/

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You can check with ps -p 360  or ps -ef | grep syslogd if you don't believe me. That ASL Sender Statics message that syslogd sends should happen dozens of time a day. You could also check any value for any log entry of that format process[PID]  to see if I'm wrong or if I'm right about that being the pattern for all such messages logged to system.log

Thank you, I see that’s correct.  On my m1 MBP, process 360 is the syslogd process whereas on the iMac (as in my original question) 1033 is the syslogd process.  That these IDs are stable across reboots is probably due to process startup order, yet is very surprising.  Apparently this message is just stating the logger is sending or recording events, yet reveals nothing.  In my case, I’ll likely need to use the log command to figure out what's going on.  However, thanks, I would if I could accept your response as the answer.  I wouldve preferred this answer to my orig question instead however.

How about this, I’d love for you to use my comment and make the best answer as you see it. Your question is worded now it made sense to you and it will attract others that write the same search terms. Then I can vote for your answer and give you a little answer juice. Once this has two answers, we can look at reviving the original posts. Closes and deletes are all soft and can be reversed if needed by high reputation accounts.

Is https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/475147/mac-syslogd-event-id-definitions the original question you are referring to? Right now this still seems to refer to PIDs, can you rewrite based on what you learned here? Also, which problem are you trying to solve with analyzing the logs?

Hi, yes that was my original question, and it was better but I would now make it shorter like: What do these system.log messages mean.... etc?  It's been notable to learn MacOS logs it's own logger, but the second part would also be good to know.  What does "ASL Sender Statistics" mean?  If anyone has an answer to that, then I can delete this, and re-ask, and we can have a useful answer for a very common message and question.  In my case, I saw this on three computer during disconnection events.

That sounds like a good new question to ask then. You might get better answers if you also show your research done and the context you ask the question in. Also, these messages are specific to the application/daemon writing them, so it helps to focus on one application only.

I'll re-post and this post can be deleted along with my original versions.  I think an answer to this is valuable given how often these macs log these messages, but don't fully understand your comment about the application, given these log messages are written under many circumstances and the noted process is just the logger itself, and the message seems generic. Let me re-post and see if we can improve it.

There are a lot of applications/binaries logging into the system logs on macOS. Asking about the log messages triggered by one application will be an easier question to answer than asking about all messages.

Fair point, but if I'm trying to figure out why disconnection events are happening, and I don't know the cause, then I don't know the relevant application or process in question.  In any case, I re-posted, and think it's worth deleting this.

Others may have the same question, there is no need to delete. But having a real-world problem to solve is a good starting point for the new question. Let’s see whether the relevant information can be extracted from the logs.

The number after the process name is the process ID.
Every process started on macOS is given a number, the process ID, which is incremented by one for the next process (until it wraps around).
It is unrelated to the content of a log message and does not indicate any error.

I would perhaps edit in that Apple unified logging is so different than traditional syslog, trying to map old methods to the new system is a lot more work than some might think seeing a familiar file on disk. https://eclecticlight.co/2024/05/15/how-to-find-what-you-want-in-the-log/ Howard Oakley makes the best tools and exceptionally well written information as a first place to go for “essential to identify proper operation of our Mac”-type information.
